# Pass multiple scope members from controller to angular service

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS world. I am developing AngularJS SPA application. I have a controller `paymentController` which is going to use an angular custom service `paymentService`. The paymentController `$scope` has multiple members like `billerId`, `billAccount`, `paymentAmount`, etc. I want to pass all/most of these members to the function exposed by angular service. I don't know what is the best way to do so. My code is given below:

```
app.controller("paymentController", function ($scope, $rootScope, paymentService) {
    $scope.billerId;
    $scope.billAccount;
    $scope.paymentAmount;
    $scope.feeAmount=1.0;
    $scope.platform = 1;
    $scope.makePayment = function(){
        paymentService.makePayment(/*what should be passed to this function*/);
    }
});
```

Please suggest me the ideal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to create a object with all those properties and pass the object,

```
$scope.bill ={};
$scope.bill.billerId;
$scope.billAccount;
$scope.bill.paymentAmount;
$scope.bill.feeAmount=1.0;
$scope.bill.platform = 1;

 $scope.makePayment = function(){
        paymentService.makePayment($scope.bill);
 }
```

Comment: Does that object have to be inside $scope? Can I declare a local variable (var bill) and assign it the values before passing it to service?